# Chaining animation CSS

Tags: css

Trying to do a chained animation effect, however the animation delay for both divs are not being applied, meaning the animation is being applied a the same time - not given the wanted effect :)

```
   <div class = "row-1 row">
        <img src = "hunger.jpeg" class = "first img">
        <img src = "hunger.jpeg" class = "second img">
    </div>


.row .img{
    width:33.3%;
    margin-right:-3px;
    animation:fadein 2s;    
}

.row .img .first{
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.row .img .second{
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein{
    from {opacity:0;}
    to {opacity:1;}
}
```

Comment: `.row .img.first`, not `.row .img .first` (ie remove the space) same for the `.second` class

Comment: thanks :) @Akshay can I ask why this is? or some sort of reference =]

Comment: `.row .img .first` selects `.first` element that is a child element of `.img`(which is a child element of `.row`) but `.row .img.first` selects the element which has both `img` and `first` class 

`<img class = "first img">` `<-` both classes are applied to the same element